I don't understand this example for a callback function, in which we callback a function which hasn't actually been declared
In the below example from Codecademy, I don't really understand how the console can process the 'artist' parameter in a higher-order function, considering that we've only declared 'artists' up to this point?
const artists = ['Picasso', 'Kahlo', 'Matisse', 'Utamaro'];

artists.forEach(artist => {
  console.log(artist + ' is one of my favorite artists.');
});

How can we use 'artist' and not something like:
artist[i]


forEach() calls the callback function repeatedly, passing each element of artists as the argument when it calls it.

Inside forEach(), it's doing something like callback(this[i], i, this)

artist is just a single element, not the whole array.

When you call forEach, it iterates through each element of the artists array. You don't need to use array indexing like artist[i] because forEach handles the iteration for you, and artist represents each individual element directly.

thanks for the responses all - so in essence, the console understands semantically that artist is a representation of a single element within the artists array?

@NickSaunders: You may be over-thinking it.  artist is simply an argument to the function being passed to forEach.  Every time forEach internally calls that function, it provides an argument.  The console doesn't need to "semantically understand" anything.  All that's happening here is functions being called and arguments being supplied to those functions.


considering that we've only declared artists up to this point?

No, in the callback function scope artist is also declared: you've defined it as the first parameter of the arrow function.
Notice that this is neither specific to forEach nor to the console call, it's just an ordinary function parameter and used as such in the code. artist is just a variable that has the value that was passed to the function. Same as
const artists = ['Picasso', 'Kahlo', 'Matisse', 'Utamaro'];
const action = (artist) => {
  // `artist` is declared in here!
  console.log(artist + ' is one of my favorite artists.');
};
artists.forEach(action);
// or
for (const arrEl of artists) action(arrEl);


When you run the forEach(artist = > {/*something*/}), you are making the callback function, which gets called for every element in the array. The artist => part is passing artist as an argument.  Within the newly created function, you can use the artist parameter, which will be one of the artists from the artists array.  This is why you can also use .forEach() like this as well:
const artists = ['Picasso', 'Kahlo', 'Matisse', 'Utamaro'];
function printArtist(artist) {
       console.log(artist + ' is one of my favorite artists.');
}
artists.forEach(artist => printArtist(artist))


Here is a little example to illustrate what is happening behind the scenes with callBack functions.   Basically the callback function gets fed arguments inside of myForEach.  cb is the callback function, which is passed as an anonymous function, though you could just as easily pass a named function.


function myForEach(array, cb) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const args = array[i]
    cb(args)
  }
}

const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]

myForEach(myArray, (x) => {console.log(x)})

function myCallback(arg){
  console.log("hello from my callback ", arg)
}

myForEach(myArray, myCallback)



